# Web API: create query to database under context user with Windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

How can I create query to db under user that create request to Web API? I want to use `IntegratedSecurity=True` and according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.connectionstring?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlConnection_ConnectionString) it takes current Windows account credentials. How can I change it to context user?

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding to your question , you need to pass your database credentials .

if that is your case , you can use the following:

```
Data Source=servername;Initial Catalog=dbname;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=yourpass"
```

if you want to use **IntegratedSecurity=True** please note :

**IntegratedSecurity=True**  means the windows account credentials will be considered

**IntegratedSecurity=False**  means you can pass your own credentials

Comment: In general, I need to run some code under context user, but I don't know credentials,  of course.